# Different behaviour of data inside and outside a function

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary(`lengths_data`) and I compute different statistic parameters using numpy and then I store it in a new dictionary (`stats_`). Later on I use this object in a new function, but when I print this object inside the function I get the original dictionary (`lengths_data`).
Here is my code:

```
from numpy import std
from numpy import mean
from numpy import percentile

lengths_data = {}
lengths_data["Value"]=[1742, 102, 66, 30, 30, 30, 66, 30, 1473, 3798, 30, 30, 30, 30, 66, 30, 1473, 14027, 1126, 1004, 131, 250, 426, 287, 891, 4228, 463, 410, 1807, 4067, 393, 1993, 1468, 1883, 55, 3555, 7158, 3889, 1431, 131, 378, 4596, 68, 807, 757, 2042, 160, 815, 5922, 2785, 3598, 1811, 286, 540, 2407, 1414, 6873, 734, 289, 3200, 2097, 3254, 300, 1175, 3587, 2243, 3188, 4480, 684, 7155, 3070, 1811, 1724, 2218, 4928, 2874, 3394, 863, 3333, 503, 864, 1109, 794, 2480, 1749, 3367, 679, 1698, 1862, 1068, 101, 3157, 2570, 2090, 530, 5913, 535, 1708, 912, 513, 1392, 1783, 1401, 1803, 4303, 850, 134, 5234, 991, 3200, 213, 625, 718, 2315, 5230, 3994, 139, 3631, 1375, 2064, 139, 534, 2989, 1168, 3296, 3138, 4655, 1255, 281, 1669, 390, 1007, 2137, 269, 129, 2681, 1282, 716, 739, 1241, 315, 2603, 1397, 2263, 402, 2572, 1086, 1308, 9293, 810, 2486, 316, 495, 2234, 588, 483, 3949, 1481, 3266, 1301, 346, 2227, 143, 1971, 1095, 7988, 2880, 1299, 1638, 2545, 1033, 5842, 10395, 4694, 4796, 257, 6724, 513, 8380, 260, 1756, 1158, 3006, 2402, 1233, 478, 3492, 2283, 323, 1886, 167, 2264, 306, 1135, 926, 164, 3, 1031, 1307, 624, 2103, 988, 1942, 528, 928, 41, 232, 3150, 2905, 1420, 488, 16, 13, 238, 217, 559, 1367, 2790, 951, 1069, 18, 1435, 2470, 4508, 1379, 474, 692, 819, 1186, 305, 206, 4995, 2622, 60, 1041, 186, 1291, 937, 1400, 1452, 1267, 3819, 2072, 2697, 472, 735, 2237, 563, 585, 361, 2840, 658, 1948, 271, 2432, 585, 361, 2840, 658, 1948, 271, 2790, 1032, 492, 2110, 1031, 492, 749, 9, 504, 1171, 202, 3671, 9, 1682, 1032, 492, 2110, 1032, 492, 1501, 3030, 3647, 1019, 6491, 476, 1245, 2096, 1419, 359, 3110, 293, 1507, 4626, 4341, 1099, 1549, 6719, 1838, 358, 8, 2828, 379, 1129, 1168, 1295, 519, 649, 2164, 1554, 4318, 1646, 1581, 2653, 577, 4982, 1881, 1278, 2455, 1695, 4060, 3043, 380, 4285, 1573, 2107, 2103, 1666, 2568, 696, 170, 9, 3876, 1171, 504, 9, 2217, 816, 799, 4139, 183, 27, 65, 2007, 875, 1568, 2882, 443, 1089, 2080, 762, 392, 522, 2997, 4750, 759, 3255, 3690, 2765, 81, 276, 288, 54, 72, 837, 261, 2179, 1061, 3426, 415, 3838, 9, 3670, 202, 1171, 504, 9, 287, 740, 3594, 4287, 871, 214, 805, 6271, 5002, 38, 679, 2111, 1545, 1615, 5388, 224, 1683, 665, 406, 102, 1431, 1932, 2676, 209, 3565, 641, 1367, 3027, 241, 505, 54, 3177, 3066, 1061, 5175, 58, 5485, 2327, 132, 2597, 9, 986, 1373, 114, 3730, 510, 504, 1760, 1169, 1059, 1141, 955, 781, 1386, 1345, 1188, 3597, 1323, 768, 433, 1786, 462, 394, 2314, 3342, 1547, 1841, 78, 2323, 745, 119, 798, 1040, 774, 472, 542, 46, 2760, 1164, 606, 5559, 310, 4431, 980, 1806, 147, 431, 1120, 639, 1387, 3846, 508, 239, 1409, 447, 4831, 1384, 3496, 2227, 2063, 57, 483, 337, 7793, 786, 366, 4831, 1436, 152, 1632, 1980, 301, 1095, 3654, 610, 402, 2954, 539, 2428, 1386, 3229, 1471, 155, 1995, 1101, 3850, 2283, 1635, 37, 3282, 326, 163, 161, 94, 1236, 1071, 383, 499, 876, 22, 1077, 6765, 6385, 243, 2663, 1901, 3918, 21, 408, 226, 554, 191, 2430, 6269, 1297, 2582, 180, 487, 505, 2531, 3590, 4397, 2665, 687, 248, 6739, 1368, 2096, 1288, 1896, 1246, 9, 5096, 504, 9, 3276, 232, 5012, 360, 1332, 6101, 219, 214, 191, 2251, 1935, 180, 1271, 3001, 1003, 957, 2036, 9, 5090, 9, 3221, 475, 3290, 3045, 1393, 312, 1316, 85, 757, 1603, 823, 4534, 1701, 854, 826, 996, 2738, 3048, 2104, 1800, 282, 378, 1953, 1592, 2110, 820, 88, 3678, 3525, 1870, 4432, 7824, 934, 38, 955, 3398, 2021, 9, 1622, 1639, 1437, 3989, 985, 5514, 249, 1473, 30, 66, 30, 30, 30, 30, 4671, 249, 1473, 30, 66, 30, 30, 30, 30, 1581]

stats_ = {}
stats_["Value"]=[1694, 1737, 411, 2422, 3, 14027]


def lenstatistics(lengths_data):

    stats_ = dict.fromkeys(lengths_data)

    for combin in lengths_data.keys():
        mean_ = int(mean(lengths_data[combin]))
        std_ = int(std(lengths_data[combin]))
        p25_ = int(percentile(lengths_data[combin], 25))
        p75_ = int(percentile(lengths_data[combin], 75))
        min_ = min(lengths_data[combin])
        max_ = max(lengths_data[combin])
        vect = [mean_, std_, p25_, p75_, min_, max_]
        stats_[combin] = vect[:]

    return stats_

stats_ = lenstatistics(lengths_data)

# If I do print stats_ I get the values of the mean the standard deviation, and the other expected values...
print stats_

def enzymes2(stats_, length):

    print stats_
    # If I do print stats_ I get the original dictionary lengths_data, with all the data used to create the mean, the standard deviation..

     std_ = 0

    for combin in Dict1.keys():
        if length in range((stats_[combin][0] - stats_[combin][1]), (stats_[combin][0]+Stats[combin][1])):
            if std_ == 0:
                std_ = stats_[combin][1]
                combine = combin
            if std_ > stats_[combin][1]:
                std_ = stats_[combin][1]
                combine = combin
            else:
                pass

    return stats_[combine]



Selection = enzymes2(lengths_data, 1800)
```

How can I solve this? Or how can I at the end of the second function(`enzymes2`) get the expected (real) value of `stats_` (Without calculating it again)?

What I understand of the problem is that the references of `stats_` still point to `lengths_data`, but only the `__str__` method is changed and inside the other function is refreshed, but I am not sure about this...

Comment: I know its not necessary, but your code would be more easily readable if you followed the guidelines set out by PEP8 (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I suggest that you edit your code into a runnable example.  That way we don't have to assume anything about the code that we cannot see.  Also, you are likely to find your error in the process of editing.

Comment: Now I edit the code, now is runnable as if. But I need help with the guidelines @ebarr. What can I improve to follow the guidelines? I thought that I was already following the guidelines.

Comment: Use meaningful variable names.  `Dict` and `Dict1` are horribly confusing, esp. due to `dict` being one of the most popular types in Python.  Call them after their purpose, not the mechanism they use to store bits.

Comment: Some simple stuff: variable names should be all lower case. So instead of `Std` you could use `std_` (so you don't shadow the numpy function). Also avoid variable names (of any case) that are also the names of python built-ins.

Comment: It is not really clear what the problem is in this code and it appears that you are using the wrong types of containers for your data. You would be better off posting your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where people can give some feedback (this usually turns up any bugs that are left in the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem in the behaviour you are describing : in the enzymes2 method, you print Stats, which is redefined as the first parameter of the method. This means that in the context of the method, Stats is the first parameter of the method, not the global variable. And when you call enzymes2 method at the end, you pass Dict as the first parameter, so it prints Dict...

If you want to use Stats as a global variable in the context of the whole file, simply don't redefine it in the context of a method...

In your example, to get the expected result, I think you might just replace the last line by

```
Selection = enzymes2(Stats, 1800)
```

since Stats variable has already been calculated by your previous call Stats = lenstatistics(Dict)

Comment: I can't believe I am so dummy... Thanks!

Comment: As you sow, so you reap :) When you pass Dict to the function, it will print Dict!